# The Rotated Crossword

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

This rotated crossword works just the same as a regular crossword. Only exception being that, after you've found the solution to a clue, you don't put this word directly into the grid. Instead, you rotate the word first; not once, but twice. The numbers next to the clues tell you how to rotate the words.

N.B.: All rotated words are existing English words.

> | ACROSS | DOWN |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2. Guide (1,1) | 1. Lights (19,3) |
> | 4. Truly, ___, Deeply (8,1) | 3. Perhaps (7,3) |
> | 6. Visual (18,3) | 4. Many times (13,3) |
> | 7. Goddess of nature (5,4) | 5. Exhausted (10,3) |
> | 9. Fan (23,2) | 8. Synthetic fabric (6,2) |
> | 12. Oak nut (24,4) | 9. Hawaiian greeting (13,3) |
> | 14. Uteri (16,3) | 10. Cut the grass (14,1) |
> | 15. Nuts and ___ (25,1) | 11. Inexpensive (11,3) |
> | 17. Make very happy (7,4) | 13. Like stuffed animals (13,4) |
> | 18. Smooths (11,2) | 16. Leaves (8,1) |

[image: Grid]

Comment: Are you sure, the "visual" notations are correct? i am getting some weird stuffs.

Comment: @Sid: correct, should have been 18,3.

Comment: Dat latex... impressive $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER:**

> And I figured out the rules by chance by playing with the words after Rot N.We have to First Rot N with the 1st number given and then, rotate the words from the index position given in the 2nd number with 2 meaning the 4th letter, 1 meaning the 5th letter,4th meaning the 2nd letter and so on.

Here's the complete answer:

The clues: (First across and then Down)

> 2.Steer-> **Stuff**(Rot 1 and starting with the last letter).(Found by Ankoganit)
>  4.Madly-> **Guilt**
>  6.Optic->**Laugh** (It is (18,3) and not (17,3) as given(Found by Deusovi in TSL)
>  7.Nymph->**Drums**
>  9.Lover->**Boils**
>  12.acorn->**amply**
>  14.Wombs->**Crime**
>  15.Bolts->**ranks**
>  17.Elate->**Shall**
>  18.Sands->**Oddly**
>  **(Down)**
>  1.Lamps->**Filet**(Found by Ankoganit)
>  3.Maybe->**Filth**
>  4.Often->**Grabs**
>  5.Tired->**Bonds**
>  8.Nylon->**Utter**
>  9.Aloha->**bunny**
>  10.mowed->**Racks**
>  11.cheap->**plans**
>  13.furry->**heels**
>  16.pages->**axiom**

Crossword:

> [image: CrosswordImage]

Comment: 1: LAMPS>FILET, 2: STEER>STUFF

Answer (score 9):

The basic idea of the puzzle is to

> Answer the standard crossword clue posed, rotate each letter of that clue with a Ceaser cipher based on the first number given, then rotate the word right a number of letters based on the second number given.

An example is here:

> 3: Perhaps->Maybe; Maybe-(10)>thfil; thfil-(3)>FILTH; which goes into the crossword.

My solving so far has brought me to here:

> [image: crossword]